# Carry STRef implicitly in an environment during computation

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, monads, monad-transformers

I am working on some bigger computation that requires use of mutable data in some critical moments. I want to avoid IO as much as I can.
My model used to constist of `ExceptT` over `ReaderT` over `State` datatype, and now I want to replace `State` with mentioned `ST`.

To simplify, let's assume I would like to keep single `STRef` with an `Int` during the whole computation, and let's skip the `ExceptT` outer layer. My initial idea was to put `STRef s Int` into `ReaderT`'s environment:

```
{-#LANGUAGE Rank2Types#-}
{-#LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification#-}

data Env = Env { supply :: forall s. STRef s Int }
data Comp a = forall s. Comp (ReaderT Env (ST s) a)
```

And the evaluator:

```
runComp (Comp c) = runST $ do
   s <- newSTRef 0
  runReaderT c (Env {supply = s})  -- this is of type `ST s a`
```

...and it fails because

> Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘s1’

Which seems to be clear, because I have mixed two separate phantom ST states. However, I have no idea how to bypass it. I have tried adding phantom `s` as `Comp` and `Env` parameter, but the result was the same and the code got uglier (but less suspicious because of lack of these `forall`s).

The feature I am trying to achieve here is to make `supply` accessible at any time, but not passed explicitly (it does not deserve it). The most comfortable place to store it is in the environment, but I see no way in initializing it.

I know there is such a thing like `STT` monad transformer which may help here, but it is not compatible with more ambitious data structures like hashtables (or is it?), so I don't want to use it as long as I cannot freely use classic `ST` libraries there.

How to properly design this model? By "properly" I mean not only "to typecheck" but to "to be nice to the rest of the code" and "as flexible as possible".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`runST` must be given a polymorphic argument, and you want your argument to come from `Comp`. Ergo `Comp` must contain a polymorphic thing.

```
newtype Env s = Env { supply :: STRef s Int }
newtype Comp a = Comp (forall s. ReaderT (Env s) (ST s) a)

runComp (Comp c) = runST $ do
    s <- newSTRef 0
    runReaderT c (Env s)
```

Because `Comp` closes over `s`, you can't make an action which returns the contained `STRef`; but you can expose an action which uses the reference internally:

```
onRef :: (forall s. STRef s Int -> ST s a) -> Comp a
onRef f = Comp $ asks supply >>= lift . f
```

e.g. `onRef readSTRef :: Comp Int` and `` onRef (`modifySTRef` succ) :: Comp () ``. Another choice that might be more ergonomic is to make `Comp` itself monomorphic, but have `runComp` demand a polymorphic action. So:

```
newtype Comp s a = Comp (ReaderT (Env s) (ST s) a)

runComp :: (forall s. Comp s a) -> a
runComp act = runST $ case act of
    Comp c -> do
        s <- newSTRef 0
        runReaderT c (Env s)
```

Then you can write

```
getSup :: Comp s (STRef s Int)
getSup = Comp (asks supply)
```

Comment: How to create monadic action to get this `STRef`?  When I try to type `getSup = Comp $ asks supply` I get typechecker error

Comment: Also, I would like to have `Comp Int` that will read this ref and put as result

Comment: @radrow You can't return the reference with this setup, but you can *use* it. I'll add a small snippet about this.