# Modify ST dependent environment in ReaderT – problem with `local` function

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, reader-monad, st-monad

This question is a sequel of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317095/4400060

I was asking there about carrying `STRef` in `ReaderT`'s environment and performing ST-actions under it. My setup now looks like:

```
import Data.HashTable.ST.Cuckoo as HT

-- |Environment for Comp
newtype Env s = Env { dataspace :: HashTable s Int Data
                    , namespace :: Map Name Int }

-- |Main computation monad
newtype Comp a = Comp (forall s. ReaderT (Env s) (ST s) a)


-- |Evaluate computation
runComp (Comp c) = runST $ do
    ds <- HT.new
    runReaderT c (Env ds empty)


-- |Perform an action on `dataspace` hashmap
onDataspace :: (forall s. HashTable s Int Data -> ST s a) -> Comp a
onDataspace f = Comp $ asks dataspace >>= lift . f
```

And it works cool in general – I can access or modify `dataspace` in place freely. However, when I have added immutable `namespace` I started to struggle. Feature I need is running `Comp` action with updated `namespace` in the way that it won't affect further computations' namespaces – exactly what `local` does.

First of all I wanted to write `MonadReader` instance for `Comp`, however I faced the `ST`'s phantom type and got `illegal instance` error:

```
instance MonadReader (Env s) Comp where {}
instance MonadReader (forall s. Env s) Comp where {}
instance forall s. MonadReader (Env s) Comp where {}
```

Full error message:

```
Illegal instance declaration for
     ‘MonadReader (EvalEnv s) Evaluator’
     The coverage condition fails in class ‘MonadReader’
       for functional dependency: ‘m -> r’
     Reason: lhs type ‘Evaluator’
       does not determine rhs type ‘EvalEnv s’
     Un-determined variable: s
```

I understand this error, but I see no way bypassing it. To be honest I don't really require full `local` function. I only need to be able to run `Comp` with different `namespace`, but same `dataspace`.

The best solution would be to provide full `MonadReader` instance. I am aware that it might not be possible, so as a workaround I would like to have a function

```
withNs :: Map Name Int -> Comp a -> Comp a
```

---

Summarizing: I want to be able to run `Comp` with modified `namespace` while leaving `dataspace` unchanged as a reference keeping all changes under it.

How to do that? I can accept modifying my initial setup if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope parameter `s` of `ST` should remain outside:

```
newtype Comp s a = Comp (ReaderT (Env s) (ST s) a)
```

The only place where you need a higher-rank type is when calling `runST`.

```
runComp :: (forall s. Comp s a) -> a
runComp = runST $ do
  ds <- HT.new
  runReaderT c (Env ds empty)
```

Everywhere else you can simply be parametric in `s`.

```
doStuff :: Comp s Bool
doMoreStuff :: Comp s Int
```

Then the `MonadReader` instance can be written:

```
instance MonadReader (Env s) (Comp s) where
  ...
```